# Redefining a Variable in terms of itself vs creating a new one

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, summation, notation

Suppose I want to show

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}ar^{n-1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}ar^{n}$$

Is it acceptable to increment $n$ by redefining it in terms of itself, i.e., $n = n+1$ (written n+=1 in many programming languages), and thus write

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}ar^{n-1} = \sum_{n+1=1}^{\infty}ar^{(n+1)-1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}ar^{n}$$

Or is it better to define  a dummy variable $m=n-1 \implies n=m+1$ and proceed as follows?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}ar^{n-1}=\sum_{m+1=1}^{\infty}ar^{(m+1)-1}=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}ar^{m}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}ar^{n}$$

Comment: To do this formally there would probably be two steps: first a substitution $m=n-1$ on the sum and second renaming the bound variable $m$ to $n$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables). However it's very common to do both together as in your first alternative (just be careful not to confuse the "new $n$" with the "old $n$").

Comment: @stewbasic As justification for the last step I was thinking that at each iteration $x$, the notation defines $n=x$ and $m=x$ and thus by transitivity $\forall x(n=m)$....

Comment: It is also common to use arrows instead of the equal sign, like "$n\leftarrow n+1$", as the equal sign isn't an assignment sign in mathematics.

Comment: @user251257 that is a good point, and a good way to clear things up. I've also seen (and prefer) the notation $:=$ to mean "is defined to be equal to."

Comment: @EvanRosica yes, but it is often used to declare a new variable. In computer science it is also used as assignment.

Comment: The particular example you give is so common that it has its own name: reindexing the series.

Comment: Easier would be to go: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}ar^{n-1} = \sum_{n-1=0}^{\infty}ar^{n-1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}ar^{n}$